# Get value of text box that have id with special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a some text boxe with id that contains special character like '(' and ')' . when i am accessing value of this text boxe i am getting value as undefined .need solution of this problem ...

```
  <input type="text" id="header_COUNT(SUBJECT)"  onblur="javascript:setHeader();" disabled="disabled">
```

script is

```
function setHeader(){
var val=$('#header_COUNT(SUBJECT)').val();
console.log(val);

}
```

Comment: An ID can't contain those characters, at least not in HTML 4. [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/70579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not such a complex selector. You can use `getElementById`:

```
var val=$(document.getElementById('header_COUNT(SUBJECT)')).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape characters in jQuery with 2 backslashes `\\`

So reference it like:

```
$('#header_COUNT\\(SUBJECT\\)')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6Qmj/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
function setHeader(){
var val=$('input[id="header_COUNT(SUBJECT)"]').val();
console.log(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/upomut/1/edit)

```
var id_with_special_chars = 'header_COUNT(SUBJECT)';
var value =  $('input[id="'+id_with_special_chars+'"]').val();

alert(value);
```

Comment: Whoops, @Ashwin beat me to it